# Update field with combined contents from other fields

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a Persons table that has a field for first_name and another field for last_name. I want to join this table with another which contains full_name (first_last).  I would like to produce a field in my Persons table called full_name which is created by combining first_name space and last_name.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to join the Persons table with the other table without producing another field in the Persons Table.

The join can be made by combining the first_name and last_name fields together as a string

```
SELECT
    P.first_name
   ,P.last_name
   ,T.full_name
FROM Persons P
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_Other T
      ON P.first_name & '_' & P.last_name = T.full_name
```